# What is the time-complexity of the following code snippet?

Tags: time-complexity

```
int a = 0, i = N; 
while (i > 0) { 
 a += i; 
 i /= 2; 
}
```

According to me the complexity should be O(N/2) but the answer is O(logN). Can somebody help me understand this?

Comment: i /= 2 makes it O(log(N)) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is easily disproven by a simple example. Let's assume `N = 32`. The iterations would look as follows:

```
1: i = 32
2: i = 16
3: i = 8
4: i = 4
5: i = 2
6: i = 1
7: i = 0 (loop aborted)
```

This gives an iteration count of `6` whereas your assumption would be `32/2 = 16`. I assume you're way of thinking about it that `i` gets halved once, but instead it gets halved every iteration, making it `O(log(n))`.